# Building custom boost librares

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build

Isn't there an easy way to select the source files and build them with all multithreading options `(/MT, /MTd, /MD, /MDd)` for MSVC v.8?

I've seen this command,

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_46_1> bjam ^
More? --build-dir="C:\Documents and Settings\dave\build-boost" ^
More? --build-type=complete msvc stage
```

from MSVC Command prompt, but this process takes very long on my OS, like upto 10 hours, running on 1.66 Ghz Intel Duo Core, with 512 RAM.

How can i select the librares that I want to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further down on the [page you quote from](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source):

> In particular, to limit the amount of time spent building, you may be interested in:
>   reviewing the list of library names with --show-libraries
>   limiting which libraries get built with the --with-library-name or --without-library-name options
>   choosing a specific build variant by adding release or debug to the command line.